# How to override style in NativeBase?

Tags: react-native, native-base

In every code example mentioned in [NativeBase Docs](http://nativebase.io/documentation), there's no usage of React StyleSheet.
I didn't find a way to override styles of NativeBase.
How can I include React StyleSheet into my app?

Comment: You could also try filing an issue [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues) if you think the docs aren't updated/carry less information.

Answer (score 2):

NativeBase uses a different approach to add styling to your component.

It uses a [Utility first](https://docs.nativebase.io/utility-first) approach, wherein it leverages the ReactNative stylesheets API and adds a layer of [Utility Props](https://docs.nativebase.io/utility-props) on top of it. The idea is to pass props to your component to change their styling, instead of defining a className and adding styles in a separate stylesheet.

For example, with React Native, you would write:

```
function Example() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* content */}
    </View>;
  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#0891b2',
    paddingVertical: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 375,
    maxWidth: '100%'
  }
});
```

Now, with NativeBase, to achieve the same view, you would write it as follows:

```
function Example() {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Box bg="primary.600" py="4" px="3" rounded="md" width={375} maxWidth="100%">
        {/* content */}
      </Box>
    </NativeBaseProvider>;
  );
}
```

Here, NativeBase has already defined `bg`, `py`, `px`, etc. as props and mapped them to the styling properties of `backgroundColor`, `paddingVertical` , `paddingHorizontal`, etc. respectively.

There is a list of these mappings provided [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/utility-props#h2-style-props), which you can simply refer to add any styling that you may need for your component.

Answer (score 0):

For NativeBase usually if you want customize the appearance you need to do it at a theme level and not a component/widget level.

http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.2/customize

I believe the reason it this keeps the UI consistent.

Have a look at the source code for all the widgets that you are trying to override the style for:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/Components/Widgets/

There are certain cases where you can amend certain aspects e.g. for the button 
`this.props.style` is used anywhere but `this.props.textStyle`

So you can override the textStyle when you define the component:

```
<Button textStyle={{...}}/>
```

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/Components/Widgets/Button.js